# Based vs Located

Tags: word-choice

Do these two sentences imply different meanings?

> Our company is based in Melbourne, Australia.
>
> Our company is located in Melbourne, Australia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say so, yes.

It's subtle, though.

"based" implies that you are speaking of a head office even though the business may have sub-offices.

Some employee in the US might say: "Sony is based in Japan" [although they probably have offices in America]

"located" is simply specifying the location.

"The Sony head office is located in Japan"

"Based in" simply adds a bit of information about where the main office of a company is. Not always the case, but in many cases.

Comment: True, except that no one would say that Kodak is based in Japan. :)

Comment: Had a friend who worked for Kodak. He always was talking about transferring to Japan... so it stuck in my head for some reason. I'll change it to... Sony!

Comment: Agree, but would point out that using based in X implies that there are significant operations elsewhere, whereas located in Y implies that essentially the entire operation is there.

Answer (score 0):

For how I understand it, *based at Shirley* means the center of operations are on Shirley, while *located in Shirley* could refer to one of the agencies of the business.